# Determining household size with groupby

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, counting

I have a dataframe with individuals and their household IDs and I would like to create a variable that contains the household size.

I am using Python 3.7. I tried to use the groupby function combined with the size (I tried count as well count) function. The idea is for each observation about an individual, I want to count in the dataframe the number of observations with the same household ID and store it in a new variable.

Consider that each observation has a household ID (hh_id) and that I would like to store the household size in the hh_size variable.

I tried the following:

`df['hh_size'] = df.groupby('hh_id').size`

I expect hh_size variable to contain for each observation the household size. However, I get a column with only nan.

When I use`df.groupby('hh_id').size` alone, I get the expected result but I cannot manage to store it in the hh_size variable.

```
For example: 

 individual    hh_id  hh_size
  1             1      2
  2             1      2
  3             2      1
  4             3      1  


Thanks, 
Julien
```

Comment: Can you show some code? You question is not clear.

Comment: I did show some code but I'm happy to clarify. I have a dataframe with observations about individuals. Each individual has a household id (hh_id). I would like to create a new variable, hh_size, that counts for each observation, the total number of individuals that have the same hh_id. I will add an example in my original comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it you have to convert it to new `DataFrame` - `.to_frame(name='hh_size')` - and you may have to reset index.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'individual': [1,1,2,2,3,4],
    'hh_id':      [1,1,1,1,2,3],
})

sizes = df.groupby(['individual', 'hh_id']).size()

new_df = sizes.to_frame(name='hh_size').reset_index()

print(new_df)
```

Result:

```
   individual  hh_id  hh_size
0           1      1        2
1           2      1        2
2           3      2        1
3           4      3        1
```